# Pandas count sequence of negative values in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have values in Pandas Dataframe column “B” that can be positive or negative:

```
data=[[5889.25, 738.0],
 [5896.5, 49.0],
 [5897.5, 130.0],
 [5899.5, -266.0],
 [5903.75, -126.0],
 [5903.75, -512.0],
 [5898.75, -141.0],
 [5897.5, -303.0],
 [5895.0, -107.0],
 [5893.25, 27.0]]

pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B'])

    A   B
0   5889.25 738.0
1   5896.50 49.0
2   5897.50 130.0
3   5899.50 -266.0
4   5903.75 -126.0
5   5903.75 -512.0
6   5898.75 -141.0
7   5897.50 -303.0
8   5895.00 -107.0
9   5893.25 27.0
```

What is fast pythonic way to make column “C” that counts how many rows is number in “B” negative? So the dataframe would look like:

```
    A   B   C
0   5889.25 738.0   0
1   5896.50 49.0    0
2   5897.50 130.0   0
3   5899.50 -266.0  1
4   5903.75 -126.0  2
5   5903.75 -512.0  3
6   5898.75 -141.0  4
7   5897.50 -303.0  5
8   5895.00 -107.0  6
9   5893.25 27.0    0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to find the negative values then use `groupby` and `cumcount()+1`

```
data=[[5889.25, 738.0],
 [5896.5, 49.0],
 [5897.5, 130.0],
 [5899.5, -266.0],
 [5903.75, -126.0],
 [5903.75, -512.0],
 [5898.75, -141.0],
 [5897.5, -303.0],
 [5895.0, -107.0],
 [5893.25, 27.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B'])
df['C'] = np.where(df['B']>0,0,df.groupby(np.where(df['B']<0,0,df['B'])).cumcount()+1)
```

Output :

```
         A      B  C
0  5889.25  738.0  0
1  5896.50   49.0  0
2  5897.50  130.0  0
3  5899.50 -266.0  1
4  5903.75 -126.0  2
5  5903.75 -512.0  3
6  5898.75 -141.0  4
7  5897.50 -303.0  5
8  5895.00 -107.0  6
9  5893.25   27.0  0
```

If you want to create a sequence for every positive number you can write a function

```
count = 0
def count_neg(x):
    global count
    if x < 0:
        count+=1
    else :
        count = 0 
    return count
df['C'] = df['B'].apply(count_neg)
```

Output :

```
        A      B  C
0  5889.25 -738.0  1
1  5896.50  -49.0  2
2  5897.50  130.0  0
3  5899.50 -266.0  1
4  5903.75 -126.0  2
5  5903.75 -512.0  3
6  5898.75 -141.0  4
7  5897.50 -303.0  5
8  5895.00 -107.0  6
9  5893.25   27.0  0
```

Comment: Your solution continue to counts all the negative numbers in one sequence (so in next sequence the negative number starts with 7 etc). How to reset the counter after each positive number?

Comment: @PeterL Did you find a solution to reset the counter for each positive value?

Comment: @cJc I did put the solution for resetting the counter .It is done with the help of function defined manually. If you have any built in func to do that it will be great